# finding outliers and counting number of occurrence

Tags: r

I have a data frame as below

```r
raw_data <- data.frame(
  "id" = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2),
  "salary" = c(10000,15000,20000,40000,50000),
  "expenditure" = c(10000,15000,20000,30000,40000))
```

if a salary greater than 15000 would be flaged as an outlier, and if an expenditure is greater than 10000, it should be flaged as an outlier. But the problem is now, how to count how many times an outlier (both spearately) occured by a specific id. The output should look like the following df

```r
output <- data.frame(
  "id"=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2),
  "question_name"=c("expenditure", "salary","expenditure","salary","expenditure","salary","expenditure"),
  "values"=c(15000,20000,20000,30000,40000,500000,40000),
  "count"=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1))
```

Comment: You mean this? `sum(raw_data$salary > 15000)`

Comment: no what I mean is find how many outlier is there suppose in salary column and count each value how  many time that outlier occurred by an id.

suppose id=1 entered 4 times 15000 the output should be like
```
output<-data.frame("id"=1,"title"=c("salary"),
"value"=15000, "count"=4)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Raw data is :

```
    raw_data <- data.frame("id" = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2), 
                           "salary" = c(10000,15000,20000,40000,50000), 
                           "expenditure" = c(10000,15000,15000,30000,40000))
```

And the solution is :

```
    raw_data <- raw_data %>% filter(salary>15000 | expenditure>10000)
    entry_variables <- raw_data %>%select(id,salary,expenditure) %>% 
      pivot_longer(cols = -id,
                   names_to = "Question_name", values_to= "Value", 
                   values_drop_na = TRUE) %>%
      count(id, Question_name, Value)
```

Comment: @MacOS  this is what I wanted thank you guys for helping :)

Comment: I see. Can you please mark this as the correct solution? Any maybe mark my answer with an upvote if it is correct? That way others can see the correct answer and can also see alternatives. Thank you!

Comment: @MacOS sure ill mark your answer with an upvote  you can mark my solution as well if you find it interesting

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `dplyr` solution:

```
raw_data %>% 
  mutate(salary_flag =
           ifelse(salary > 15000, 1, 0),
         expenditure_flag = ifelse(expenditure > 10000, 1, 0)) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(total_outlier = sum(salary_flag) + sum(expenditure_flag))
```

You are flagging for `salary` and `expenditure`, then grouping by `id` and calculating the sum of all `salary_flag` and the sum of all `expenditure_flag` for each `id`.

```
 id salary expenditure salary_flag expenditure_flag total_outlier
  <int>  <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>            <dbl>         <dbl>
1     1  10000       10000           0                0             0
2     2  15000       15000           0                1             1
3     3  20000       20000           1                1             2
4     4  40000       30000           1                1             2
5     5  50000       40000           1                1             2
```

If you're only concerned with the total outliers, @MartinGal provided a very nice option:

```
raw_data %>% 
group_by(id) %>% 
mutate(total_outlier = sum(salary>15000, expenditure>10000))
```

Gives us:

```
     id salary expenditure total_outlier
  <int>  <dbl>       <dbl>         <int>
1     1  10000       10000             0
2     2  15000       15000             1
3     3  20000       20000             2
4     4  40000       30000             2
5     5  50000       40000             2
```

edit:

This seems to get the end result that you're looking for:

```
raw_data %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  summarise(count = sum(salary>15000, expenditure>10000),
            value = min(salary)) %>% 
  mutate(title = "salary") %>% 
  select(id, title, value, count)
```

Which gives you:

```
     id title  value count
  <int> <chr>  <dbl> <int>
1     1 salary 10000     0
2     2 salary 15000     1
3     3 salary 20000     2
4     4 salary 40000     2
5     5 salary 50000     2
```

Comment: A little bit simplyfied: `raw_data %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(total_outlier = sum(salary>15000, expenditure>10000))`.

Comment: @MartinGal very elegant solution! I wasn't sure if the individual flags needed to be seen or not. I'll update the post with your solution as well.

Comment: @Matt that is a good solution but what I want is different like
 what I mean is to find how many outlier is there in a column suppose in salary column and count each value how many time that outlier occurred  or entered by a specific id.

suppose id=1 entered 4 times 15000 the output should be like
```
output<-data.frame("id"=1,"title"=c("salary"),
"value"=15000, "count"=4)

Comment: @MartinGal what I want is like this to check a specific column and count  how  many times an id entered same outlier suppose id=1 in salary column has entered 20000 four times the out put should be like 
output<- data.frame("id"=1, "title"=c("salar"),"value"=20000,"count"=4)

Comment: @MartinGal please see my edit and let me know if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: @Matt Thank you but it counts 20000 in both salary and expenditure and that is 2 what i want is 
raw_data <- data.frame("id" = c(1,2,3,3,4), 
                       "salary" = c(10000,15000,20000,20000,50000), 
                       "expenditure" = c(10000,15000,20000,30000,40000))
referring above data frame id=3 entered two times 20000 which is an outlier I want the output to show
id=3, title=salary, value=20000, count=2 
the same way if any other id enter same outlier we have to count

Comment: @MacOS yes and I did a reply good solution we are almost there but need a little changes 
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following

```
raw_data <- data.frame("id" = 1:5, 
                       "salary" = c(10000,15000,20000,40000,50000), 
                       "expenditure" = c(10000,15000,20000,30000,40000))

raw_data$SaleryOutlier <- ifelse(
    raw_data$salary > 15000, TRUE, FALSE)

raw_data$ExpenditureOutlier <- ifelse(
    raw_data$expenditure > 10000, TRUE, FALSE)
```

You can then use `aggregate` function to summarize the data, e.g. for each id by using `FUN=sum`. This should look like

```
aggregate(raw_data, by=list(id = raw_data$id), FUN=sum)
```

This works because `TRUE=1`.

I hope this helps.

**EDIT**

Based on your comment, I guess you are looking for

```
raw_data <- data.frame("id" = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2), 
                       "salary" = c(10000,15000,20000,40000,50000), 
                       "expenditure" = c(10000,15000,20000,30000,40000))

raw_data$SaleryOutlier <- ifelse(
  raw_data$salary > 15000, TRUE, FALSE)

raw_data$ExpenditureOutlier <- ifelse(
  raw_data$expenditure > 10000, TRUE, FALSE)

raw_data_aggregate <- aggregate(raw_data, by=list(id = raw_data$id), FUN=sum)

raw_data_aggregate$count <- raw_data_aggregate$SaleryOutlier + raw_data_aggregate$ExpenditureOutlier
```

**EDIT TWO**

If you want to `aggregate` over two variables, just exchange the above `aggregate` with

```
raw_data_aggregate <- aggregate(
  SalaryOutlier + ExpenditureOutlier ~ id + salary + expenditure, raw_data, FUN=sum)
```

**EDIT THREE**

Based on the comments below, I created the following code

```
raw_data <- data.frame(
  "id" = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2),
  "salary" = c(10000,15000,20000,40000,50000),
  "expenditure" = c(10000,15000,20000,30000,40000))

# Identify salary outliers
raw_data$SalaryOutlier <- ifelse(
  raw_data$salary > 15000, TRUE, FALSE)

# Identify expenditure outliers
raw_data$ExpenditureOutlier <- ifelse(
  raw_data$expenditure > 10000, TRUE, FALSE)

# Aggregate over id + salay
raw_data_aggregate_salary <- aggregate(
  SalaryOutlier ~ id + salary, raw_data, FUN=sum)

# Aggregate over id + expenditure
raw_data_aggregate_expenditure <- aggregate(
  ExpenditureOutlier ~ id + expenditure, raw_data, FUN=sum)

# Just some renaming to fit with desired output data frame.
raw_data_aggregate_salary$question_name <- "salary"
raw_data_aggregate_expenditure$question_name <- "expenditure"

colnames(raw_data_aggregate_salary)[2] <- "values"
colnames(raw_data_aggregate_expenditure)[2] <- "values"

colnames(raw_data_aggregate_salary)[3] <- "count"
colnames(raw_data_aggregate_expenditure)[3] <- "count"

# Bind result together into one df.
raw_data_aggregate <- rbind(
  raw_data_aggregate_salary, raw_data_aggregate_expenditure)

# Only select entries where we actually have a count.
raw_data_aggregate <- subset(
  raw_data_aggregate,
  raw_data_aggregate$count > 0)

# Order to fit with desired output
raw_data_aggregate <- raw_data_aggregate[ order(raw_data_aggregate$id), ]
```

Comment: but what I want is different like what I mean is to find how many outlier is there in a column suppose in salary column and count each value how many time that outlier occurred or entered by a specific id. suppose id=1 entered 4 times 15000 the output should be like ``` output<-data.frame("id"=1,"title"=c("salary"), "value"=15000, "count"=4)

Comment: Thank you we are almost there but I want like below:
as per above data.frame
output should be like
 id=1 question_name= salary value=20000 count=1
id=1 question_name=expenditure  value=15000 count=1
id=2 question_name= salary value= 40000 count=1
id=2 question_name=salary  value=50000 count=1
id=1 question-name= expenditure value= 20000 count=1
id= 2 question_name expenditure value=30000 count=1
suppose id=1 enter two times 20000 in expenditure column output should be like
id=1 question-name=expenditure value=20000 count=2
hope that it is clear now 
Thank you in advance

Comment: Oh, you also want to group by expenditure?

Comment: see the output should be as below:

output <- data.frame("id"=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2), 
                     "question_name"=c("expenditure","salary","expenditure","salary","expenditure","salary","expenditure"), 
                     "values"=c(15000,20000,20000,30000,40000,500000,40000),"count"=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1))

Comment: Ah, I see now. Can you also please provide the input df? That way I can just copy and paste. Thank you!

Comment: here you go
raw_data <- data.frame("id" = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2), 
                       "salary" = c(10000,15000,20000,40000,50000), 
                       "expenditure" = c(10000,15000,20000,30000,40000))

Comment: @MaxMiak Please see my third edit. It produces the output you wanted. I hope I got it this time.

Comment: Thank your solution is good even I posted a solution for it after trial and error process much lesser code I will accept your solution you can vote my solution as well

Comment: Great! Please don't forget to mark you answer as the correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

In a `data.table` this would look like

```
raw_data[, flag0 := (salary > 15000) + (expenditure > 10000)]
raw_data[, flag := sum(flag0), by = "id"]
```

Here `flag0` is the flag by row (which can later be deleted if you like) and `flag` would be the final result.

Edit: Seeing your reply to @Matt, you seem to want the total amount by salary and expenditure seperately. You can do something like

```
raw_data[, flag_salary := as.integer(salary > 15000)]
raw_data[, flag_expenditure := as.integer(expenditure > 10000)]
raw_data[, flag_salary := sum(flag_salary), by = "id"]
raw_data[, flag_expenditure := sum(flag_expenditure), by = "id"]
```

Comment: but what I want is different like
 what I mean is to find how many outlier is there in a column suppose in salary column and count each value how many time that outlier occurred  or entered by a specific id.

suppose id=1 entered 4 times 15000 the output should be like
```
output<-data.frame("id"=1,"title"=c("salary"),
"value"=15000, "count"=4)